# Access to XMLHttpRequest blocked by CORS policy Error

Tags: codeigniter, vue.js, axios

[image]I'm developing a web app using codeigniter along with vue.js. I'm also using axios as routing helper. I've this JS file in `app/src/main.js`.

**main.js**

```
router.beforeEach((to,from,next)=>{
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('token');

next();
```

});

When I'm passing my header to another vue (say, login) I'm having an error saying:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/app/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable CORS. Depending on the app there are various ways to do this, I usually do it on the backend.

More here: https://enable-cors.org/

Comment: I've added CROS in `header()`. header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");